# opacity fade only works in debug mode

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I am trying to add a fade between two images using javascript:

```
    function swap(test){

    if(test==2){

    document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = "<img src=\"_images/"+showList[showIndex][3]+".jpg\" width=\"400\" />"; // Sets top invisible div to old picture

    showIndex++;

    var elem = document.getElementById("top");
    elem.style.transition = "";
    elem.style.opacity =1; // makes old picture visible

        document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = "<img src=\"_images/"+showList[showIndex][3]+".jpg\" width=\"400\" />";
    } // Set's bottom div to New picture

    var elem = document.getElementById("top");
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 0;  // fades out top picture to reveal new bottom pic.
}
```

Basically, I have 2 divs, top and bottom.  on load I set top to 0 opacity. (setting it up for the above script).

When I wrote the code it didn't seem fade out, it just popped into place.... until I put an alert right  before the `var elem = document.getElementById("top");` line, then it worked perfectly, so I ran it in debug (console?) mode and it works perfectly as well if I step through it one line at a time.

Does anyone know why this would happen?  Do I need some kind of delay to allow the transition to happen?

Comment: would be helpful if you put together a fiddle with required HTML/CSS/JS. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setTimeout` like this

```
function swap(test){

    if(test==2){

    document.getElementById("top").innerHTML = "<img src=\"_images/"+showList[showIndex][3]+".jpg\" width=\"400\" />"; // Sets top invisible div to old picture

    showIndex++;

    var elem = document.getElementById("top");
    elem.style.transition = "";
    elem.style.opacity =1; // makes old picture visible

        document.getElementById("bottom").innerHTML = "<img src=\"_images/"+showList[showIndex][3]+".jpg\" width=\"400\" />";
    } // Set's bottom div to New picture
setTimeout(function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("top");
    elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
    elem.style.opacity = 0;  // fades out top picture to reveal new bottom pic.
   }, 5000);//here time interval is 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sid.  It works perfectly.  I decreased the timeout function to 1 (milisecond?) and it still works perfectly.  Is this a standard way to get this type of function to work, or did you guess based on my mention of a delay?

Comment: @user2067101: setTimeout method executes a given code after the given time duration, since you wanted to do fade effect.. this was the best solution. If the answer worked for you, please upvote it and mark it as answer.